# Adding image in ArcGlobe

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcglobe

I am using ArcGlobe.

How can I add an image that is just on the side, and not associated with the globe?

I want to add a color scale, but I don't know how.

[image]

Comment: Unlike ArcMap, ArcGlobe has no Layout view so I think your only hope for doing this will be ArcObjects.

Comment: and how exactly you can do this with arcobjects, I do not know what it is. In General, is it possible to do this somehow using the Python add-in?

Comment: I thought Python AddIns were ArcMap only but https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python-addins/what-is-a-python-add-in.htm suggests they may be supported in ArcGlobe etc too. I do not program using ArcObjects.

Comment: ArcGlobe also supports it, but I do not know if it is possible to make it so that you can upload this image.